# Как отдать в Прод Dependency?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, зависимости

Логика DevDependency мне очень понятна, установил пакеты и на локалке они подтягиваются, все круто. Но когда делаю build и отправляю в прод, то там модулей Ноды уже нет.

Как скопировать Dependency в Прод при билде? Этот этап с продом мне вообще непонятен. Или пишется какой-то скрипт, который при билде копируют в папку для прода все зависимости?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Что-то мешает сделать на проде npm install?

Comment: на проде нельзя это сделать!